# How to create Onboarding\Walkthrough swift

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to create a welcome onboarding for the first time users but none of the views are loafing in the simulator, all I'm getting is a red background when the onboardingVC gets presented. Can anyone see the issue as to why the titles, buttons, and images won't appear?

This is the message I'm getting in the console:

Warning: Attempt to present <EMA.WalkthroughVC: 0x7faa2401e5b0> on <EMA.HomeVC: 0x7faa22407e00> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
FOUND ALL!!

```
let holderView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        view.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        return view
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        configure()
    }
    
    private func configure() {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: holderView.bounds)
        holderView.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        let titles = ["Hi","Welcome","real nigga"]
        
        for x in 0..<3 {
            let pageView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(x) * holderView.frame.size.width, y: 0, width: holderView.frame.size.width, height: holderView.frame.size.height))
            scrollView.addSubview(pageView)
            
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: pageView.frame.size.width-20, height: 120))
            
            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10+120+10, width: pageView.frame.size.width-20, height: pageView.frame.size.height - 60 - 130 - 15))
            
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: pageView.frame.size.height - 60, width: pageView.frame.size.width-20, height: 50))
            
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)
            pageView.addSubview(label)
            label.text = titles[x]
            
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "BankCard\(x)")
            pageView.addSubview(imageView)
            
            button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
            button.backgroundColor = .black
            button.setTitle("Continue", for: .normal)
            if x == 2 {
                button.setTitle("Get Started", for: .normal)
            }
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton), for: .touchUpInside)
            pageView.addSubview(button)

        }
    }
    
    @objc func didTapButton(_ button: UIButton) {
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

"whose view is not in the window hierarchy"
you didn't add the views that you created to the main view try to add the subviews to the main by using this one

```
self.view.addSubview(holderView)
```

also don't forget to add the frame for the holder view like that

```
UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

and inside  the view did load

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.view.addSubview(holderView)
}
```

Comment: Im still getting the same message in the console after adding that and changing the frame size